# Ajax request always fails

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send variables of username and password to a PHP file from a
JS file, but the ajax request always fails (prints fail), no idea why.

JS file:

```
<script>
    var imported = document.createElement('script');
    imported.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js';
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(imported);

    function collect() {
        var user = "joe";
        var pass = "123";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'myphp.php',
            data: {'username': user, 'password': pass},
            success: function(){
                alert("success!");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$myval = $_POST['username'];
echo($myval);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var imported = document.createElement('script');
    imported.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js';
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(imported);

    function collect() {
        var user = "joe";
        var pass = "123";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'myphp.php',
            data: {'username': user, 'password': pass},
            success: function(){
                alert("success!");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
</script>


PHP file:

<?php
$myval = $_POST['username'];
echo($myval);
?>
```

When posting with ajax you don't need EQUAL (=), that's the problem you're having.

Comment: And you're sure that you have a file called myphp.php in the same folder as this script ? Maybe open the inspecter in your browser (most likely F12), so see if you get any errors.

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder. I use the simplest code possible and it still keeps firing back "fail". Maybe the problem is in the php file? should I include something else in the file?

Comment: Nah, as long as the file exists and ajax can make contact, it should be success. Just tried your code and didn't have problems. Maybe try including jquery as a normal script, instead of the weird createElement thing. - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you change error function to error: function(error){ console.log(error); alert(error.status); alert(error.responseText); } ? You should see full error details in your browser console and HTTP status code in first alert window and response text in second. It should help us figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: OK don't know how this happened but when i'm adding another alert("value") at the end of the code I suddenly get success... But I still can't see the variable in the PHP file:
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
 echo "yes!";
}
else{
 echo "no";
}
?>
returns no

Comment: Hmm weird, well happily i could help a bit on the way, just not the last bit :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try `data:{username: user, password: pass}`, instead of `data:{'username': user, 'password': pass}`.